# How do I write Mocha tests dependent on other Mocha tests?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a series of tests I'm trying to run on an Express REST API, emphasis on the word *series*, because they need to be sequential to some degree. Let me explain:

Tests, in order:

1. API is accessible?
2. API connects and authenticates properly?
3. Auth tokens can then be used to write to the data store?
4. Auth tokens can then be used to retrieve data just written to data store?
5. Auth tokens can then be used to change data written (test if it worked with another retrieve)?

Note that these steps really only make any sense if they happen in order, and yet Mocha doesn't seem to run tests in order. I could make one test that runs Step 1, then another that runs Steps 1-2, then another that runs Steps 1-3, and so on, but that's definitely not DRY. I could also try to set up a chain of `before` and `after`s, but that doesn't seem up to conventions.

**Is there a proper way of running Mocha tests checking sequential steps in an process?**

I'm trying to **get rid of this pattern** of just adding additional steps to repeated tests...

```
describe('Api', () => {
    it('should be accessible', (done) => {
        // Try to connect:
        Api.connect((error, conn) => {
            done(error);
        });
    });

    it('should connect and authenticate properly', (done) => {
        // Try to connect:
        Api.connect((error, api) => {
            if (error) done(error);
            // Then try to authenticate:
            api.authenticate(TEST_AUTH_CREDENTIALS, (error, conn) => {
                done(error);
            });
        });
    });

    it('should allow for data to be written to the data store', (done) => {
        // Try to connect:
        Api.connect((error, api) => {
            if (error) done(error);
            // Then try to authenticate:
            api.authenticate(TEST_AUTH_CREDENTIALS, (error, conn) => {
                if (error) done(error);
                // Then try to write data:
                conn.write(generateTestData(), (error, res) => {
                    done(err);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    it('should allow for written data to be read from the data store', (done) => {
        // Try to connect:
        Api.connect((error, api) => {
            if (error) done(error);
            // Then try to authenticate:
            api.authenticate(TEST_AUTH_CREDENTIALS, (error, conn) => {
                if (error) done(error);
                let testData = generateTestData();
                // Then try to write data:
                conn.write(testData, (error, res) => {
                    if (error) done(error);
                    // Then try to read data:
                    conn.readLast((error, res) => {
                        if (error) done(error);
                        assert.equal(testData, res);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Mocha tests ARE run serially, but, if there's a failure it continues to the next test so it can seem like they're running in parallel.

From https://mochajs.org/:

> Mocha tests run serially, allowing for flexible and accurate
>   reporting, while mapping uncaught exceptions to the correct test cases

Supposedly you can make it stop after the first failure, but I haven't been able to get this flag to work:

> -b, --bail                              bail after first test failure

Example passing state between tests:

```
describe('Api', () => {
  var api, conn;

  it('should be accessible', (done) => {
    // Try to connect:
    Api.connect((error, new_api) => {
      if (error) {done(error);} else {
        api = new_api
        done();
      }
    });
  });

  it('should authenticate properly', (done) => {
    // Then try to authenticate:
    api.authenticate(TEST_AUTH_CREDENTIALS, (error, new_conn) => {
      if (error) {done(error);} else {
        conn = new_conn;
        done();
      }
    });
  });

  it('should allow for data to be written to the data store', (done) => {
    // Then try to write data:
    conn.write(generateTestData(), (error, res) => {
      if (error) {done(error);} else {
        done();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What I'm really trying to ask is how to avoid the pattern of sequential tests each building more steps on the previous steps. Connect. Connect then auth. Connect then auth then write. Connect then auth then write then read and a partridge in a pear tree. I've added an example above to better express what I mean.

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, just don’t do that.  E.g. the first two tests can save api and conn in vars outside of the tests and pass them to the following tests.  Mocha will run them sequentially.

Comment: Actually, can’t you remove all but the last test?  You already call done() at each level if there’s an error.  If needed you can add more assert()’s at each call level.

Comment: Not really, because then you have no idea what failed. You just know something didn't work.

Comment: Why, you'll get the error message and line #, the same output you'd get if the earlier test failed.  You can add more asserts if you like, but I think the output is similar.

Comment: the problem remains that every single test involving that API requires connections and such to function, so there are things that must be done, let's call them action dependencies, for every test. If there's no way of abstracting out action dependencies to prevent copying them with every test, this remains a problem

Comment: I think you're making this more complex than it is.  You can save a connection and any other required state in either in a variable defined in the scope of all the tests, or you can nest everything in one test.  Both will work.  I added an example above...